# Alternative technique to write an assembler

Tags: java, algorithm, assembly

I am writing a assembler for a particular instructions set.
The phase I am stuck at is I am using switch cases to convert the instructions to their respective
Hex code. So for 25 instructions I am using 25 cases whereby my code converts the instructions. Is there a better way to convert these instructions rather using so many switch cases. The ISA can be found here :https://docs.google.com/file/d/1uIzgSaTD-onlr6f3ltmZkGRuYpAxIKqKSvOSAYsjREeBawYD7vRE4q42i9dM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Better how? (why don't you like the switch/case statement?)

Comment: Well it's not something i don't like, am just curious if there is a better way to do this thing.

Comment: Consider a table-driven design.

Comment: That's just 25 cases, that's still perfectly manageable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I coded my assembler I had a couple of dictionaries which stored for each instruction their encoding and the callback to call for executing it (that's C#, you don't mind do you? ;) ):

```
class Processor {
    static Dictionary<string, int> _encodings = new Dictionary<string, int>() {

        { "mov", 0x00000032 },
        { "add", 0x00000051 }
        // etc.
    };

    static Dictionary<string, Action<object, object>> _callbacks = 
        new Dictionary<string, Action<object, object>>() {

            { "mov", executeMov },
            { "add", executeAdd } 
            // ect
    };

    void executeMov(object o1, object o2) {
        // ...
    }

    void executeAdd(objecy o1, object o2) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd create an array of structures describing each instruction. The structure would contain:

- instruction mnemonic (e.g. `"AND"`)
- instruction opcode (e.g. `0`)
- instruction operand type (e.g. `no operand`, `register operand`, `memory operand`, `immediate operand`, `2 register operands`, `register operand + memory operand`, `register operand + immediate operand`, `memory operand + immediate operand`, etc)

Then you could just search the array by the mnemonic and see what operands this instruction accepts and match that with those of the input assembly. If there's no match, you check if there's another version of the same instruction and the same mnemonic but with different operands and repeat matching (looks like `AND` has two flavors). If there's no match in the entire array, you fail with an error.

Simple, generic, extendable. And I'd not bother optimizing this for speed unless there's a performance requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the complexity of enumerating all the instructions at some point. But I'm bored so here's one way of moving the complexity away a bit is doing something like this, pseudocode:

```
 abstract class InstructionWriter
      void writeInstruction(file, data)

 ...lots of different instruction writers...


 void setupWriters() {
      writers = Container<InstructionWriter>(NUM_OP_CODES);
      writers[OPCODE1] = writerForOpCode1();
      writers[OPCODE2] = writerForOpCode2();
      ...
 }
```

then the actual writing can be rewritten as

```
 void writeInstructions(program) {
     file = open(binaryfile)
     for(opcode o in program) {
         writers[o.opcode].write(file, o.data);
     }
 }
```

This approach would probably be slower than a switch though with locating all the inherited functions etc, but that's just a guess.